# How to get all buttons disabled, when one button is clicked in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a simple game that allows users to pick a card, and reveal if the player has won a price or not. I want when the user clicks the card, to reveal a message if they won or not, but make sure that after one card is clicked, all buttons are disabled and the player cannot click/reveal the other 2 components/card message. 1. I cannot get the button to disable the other buttons when its clicked. 2. I'm struggling to make sure that the winning card is different each time. Here's my code

CSS:

```
.cards{
    background-color: red;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 20vh;
}

[class*=cardDisplay]{
    height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 200px;
    background: black; 
    color: white;
    margin: auto;
}

[class*=card-content]{
    display: none;
}

[class*=card-content-2]{
    display: block;
}
```

React

```
function Card({className, children}) {
    const [styling, setStyling] = useState("card-content");
    

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        setStyling("card-content-2")
        e.target.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')
       
    };

    return (
        <div className={`cardDisplay ${className}`} >
            <p className={styling}>{children}</p>
            <button type="button"  onClick={handleClick}>
              Click
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

function Game() {

    return (
        <div className="cards">
            <Card className="card-1" children="win" onClick/>
            <Card className="card-2" children="Sorry, no win"/>
            <Card className="card-3" children="Sorry, no win"/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: 1. What did you try so far for disabling other cards when one is clicked? I can only see you're trying to disable the actual clicked one right now. 2. What's the algorithm you wrote so far when "struggling" to make sure the winning card is different each time?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use state that holds the information whether or not all cards should be disabled. Then, pass a function to the card, that flips this state.

```
function Game() {
    const [cardsDisabled, setCardsDisabled] = useState(false);

    const disableAllCards = () => setCardsDisabled(true);

    return (
        <div className="cards">
            <Card className="card-1" 
                  children="win" 
                  isDisabled={cardsDisabled} 
                  disableAllCards={disableAllCards}/>
            <Card className="card-2"
                  children="Sorry, no win"
                  isDisabled={cardsDisabled}
                  disableAllCards={disableAllCards}/>
            <Card className="card-3"
                  children="Sorry, no win"
                  isDisabled={cardsDisabled}
                  disableAllCards={disableAllCards}/>
        </div>
    );
}

function Card({className, isDisabled, disableAllCards, children}) {
    const [styling, setStyling] = useState("card-content");
    

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        disableAllCards();
    };

    return (
        <div className={`cardDisplay ${className}`} >
            <p className={styling}>{children}</p>
            <button type="button"
                    disabled={isDisabled} 
                    onClick={handleClick}>
              Click
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};
```

You can then select the disabled property in CSS by using `card:disabled {...}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. The solution worked, I'm still in bootcamp and currently new to react.  I've actually learn't a lot just from stack overflow and how data flows in components